# Are packet BBS discussions archived anywhere?

Tags: packet

Now that the once-extensive network of AX.25 BBSs is all but gone, I'm wondering whether there exists any archive of the many public discussions that took place there.  It seems sad to think that the years of human conversation once held on these servers is gone forever.

Does such an archive exist and, if so, how does one access it?

Comment: Many of these systems were simply, by modern standards, very minimal, so storage capability wasn't great – so, gut feeling, no, these are among the lesser well-archived things (compared to NNTP groups, important IRC channels of "that" time – note that this might be quite a long era, and storage would require a lot of discipline and foresight that I doubt was usually available to the admins)

Answer (score 1):

Not unless individual operators did so.

When we ran the PBBS at the National Guard building at Fort Richardson we would often print out relevant messages during disaster situations.  Sometimes these messages would contribute to the daily sitrep.

More often we would retransmit them to specific users so they could be alerted.

We had a couple of funny situations where the relevant users were on the internal email system but not on the PBBS, so sometimes we would retype the messages for them.

But the idea of logging, or "monitoring" like in broadcast radio is a fairly recent development, and is used mostly to assure advertisers that the spots they pay for are actually aired.